Calculating expected count based on hierarchy structure
I am working on a hierarchy excel sheet and I need some help. In the columns A-F is depicted an organization hierarchy. I need a function that provides values for column 'Expected count'.
Here I have manually filled in what values I would like to get in column H:

I summarize the logic, how numbers in column H are calculated:
Now let's look at the last org unit in each row:

If that given cell has no value in the cell down to the right (practically the org unit has no subordinate units) than 'Expected count' = 'Team headcount'-1.
[eg. C4 has no value in the cell down to the right (D5 is empty)it means practically that 'Suborg A of Org 1.' has no subordinate units.
H4 = G4-1 = 8

If that given cell has values in the cells down to the right (practically the unit has subordinate unit or units) than 'Expected count' = 'Team headcount'-1 + number of different subordinate units x 2
[eg. C5 has 4 different values in the cells down to the right )it means practically that 'Suborg B of Org 1.' has 4 different subordinate units. H5 = G5-1+4x2= 16

If the value in column G is 0 than 'Expected count' = number of different subordinate units x 2 [eg. H2 = 1x2 =2]


The function has to work in the lower levels as well. It is only a sample of the hierarchy. There would be thousands of units and possibly 8 levels.

What is org unit? To you it may be logic, but to me it isn't.

In the columns A-F in every cell (that has value) is an org unit. The table shows the hierarchically structured departments of a company. The team headcount indicates the number of employees working on the departments. I need these numbers in a different breakdown for a program.

This formula returns the intended result in my sheet. The formula is filled down from cell J2.
=IFERROR(IF(G2=0,
ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$F$17,
XMATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),,-1)+1),(CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$F$17,
XMATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),,-1))=
XLOOKUP(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),A2:F2,,,-1))*(CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$F$17,
XMATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),,-1)+1)<>""))))*2,G2- 
1+ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$F$17,
XMATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),,-1)+1),(CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$F$17,
XMATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),,-1))=
XLOOKUP(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),A2:F2,,,-1))*(CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$F$17,
XMATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:F2)),,-1)+1)<>""))))*2),G2-1)



When using the logic provided I get different results from what you posted in the image, but following your logic:
=G2+(G2=0)-1+2*COUNTA(A2:F2)*(COUNTA(A2:F2)<COUNTA(A3:F3))
or spillable (Office 365 Beta):
=LET(data,A2:G17,
     lvl,DROP(data,,-1),
     headc,TAKE(data,,-1),
     curr,BYROW(--(lvl>""),SUM),
headc+(headc=0)-1+2*curr*(IFERROR(curr<DROP(curr,1),0)))

Office 365:
=LET(data,B3:H18,
     lvl,DROP(data,,-1),
     headc,TAKE(data,,-1),
     curr,BYROW(--(lvl>""),LAMBDA(b,SUM(b))),
headc+(headc=0)-1+2*curr*(IFERROR(curr<DROP(curr,1),0)))


including markdown of data:




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H




1
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
Level 4
Level 5
Level 6
Team Headcount
Expected count


2
Country1





0
2


3
Country1
Org1 of Country1




1
4


4
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg A of Org 1.



9
8


5
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.



9
14


6
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region1 of Suborg B


2
9


7
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region1 of Suborg B
Area1 of Region1

17
16


8
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region1 of Suborg B
Area2 of Region1

11
10


9
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region2 of Suborg B


3
10


10
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region2 of Suborg B
Area1 of Region2

17
16


11
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region2 of Suborg B
Area2 of Region2

9
8


12
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region3 of Suborg B


3
10


13
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region3 of Suborg B
Area1 of Region3

4
3


14
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region3 of Suborg B
Area2 of Region3

9
8


15
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region3 of Suborg B
Area3 of Region3

19
18


16
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region3 of Suborg B
Area4 of Region3

9
8


17
Country1
Org1 of Country1
Suborg B of Org 1.
Region4 of Suborg B


8
7




Not compact as P.b.'s :)
With Microsoft 365,

In each row, get column number for the last org in leaf_col
has_no_sub_org is mainly ISBLANK(INDEX(hierarchy, row_num + 1, leaf_col + 1))
sub_org_count = ROWS(non-empty cells in the next column for this org)

=LET(
    hierarchy, A2:F17,
    team_head_count, LAMBDA(row_num, INDEX(G2:G17, row_num)),
    row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(hierarchy)),
    expected_counts, BYROW(
        row_indices,
        LAMBDA(row_num,
            IF(
                team_head_count(row_num) = 0,
                2,
                LET(
                    row_, CHOOSEROWS(hierarchy, row_num),
                    leaf_col, COUNTA(row_),
                    has_no_sub_org, IF(
                        row_num = MAX(row_indices),
                        TRUE,
                        ISBLANK(INDEX(hierarchy, row_num + 1, leaf_col + 1))
                    ),
                    sub_org_count, IF(
                        has_no_sub_org,
                        0,
                        ROWS(
                            UNIQUE(
                                FILTER(
                                    CHOOSECOLS(hierarchy, leaf_col + 1),
                                    NOT(ISBLANK(CHOOSECOLS(hierarchy, leaf_col + 1))) *
                                        (
                                            CHOOSECOLS(hierarchy, leaf_col) =
                                                INDEX(hierarchy, row_num, leaf_col)
                                        )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    team_head_count(row_num) - 1 + sub_org_count * 2
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    expected_counts
)



Just a conventional index/match approach. Only things to mention are:
• Added an extra row and column to act as sentinels
• There will always be one blank cell included  in the range of the column to be counted, so I subtract one from the unique count
• c-ROWS(xdata) will always be negative so will take from the end of the column.
=LET(
data,A2:F17,
xdata,EXPAND(data,ROWS(data)+1,COLUMNS(data)+1,""),
headCt,G2:G17,
MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
LAMBDA(c,
LET(colIndex,XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(xdata,c,0)=""),
    restCol,TAKE(INDEX(xdata,0,colIndex),c-ROWS(xdata)),
    nextBlank,XMATCH(TRUE,restCol=""),
    u,ROWS(UNIQUE(TAKE(restCol,nextBlank)))-1,
    MAX(INDEX(headCt,c)-1,0)+2*u))))


